# linq vs ado.net performance

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am going to work with Linq data access model. Which Model performance is better? and why to use and why not to use Linq.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Linq to SQL and Entity Framework etc. all use ADO.NET internally, thus they are slower since they do more work than ADO.NET alone.

The idea is not to get the best performance but the best abstraction, model your domain with objects so you can reason about your data and the commands that operate on that data.
So it's a good idea to trade some performance for other aspects.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a trade off between abstraction level and performance, so of course, Linq To Entities or Linq To Sql, which both work on top of ADO.NET, will be slower than ADO.NET.

It is all about what level of performance you need for your particular project. If performance is more crucial for you than ease of development then go with straight DataReaders. If not then go for Linq To Entities.